# Visualization of Twitter activity over a time

Tags: data-visualization, mean

I have tweet counts for a bunch of topics by day, by week and by month. Now I want to visualize them using bar charts.

Is it a good practice to visualize the exact counts or shall I take weekly averages and visualize them?

Comment: What do you mean by **exact counts**?  And what is your problem statement?  What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have the number of tweets for each day for a given term like #linux. I am trying to see if there is a peak of interest in any of the technologies at a given period and trying to correlate with any major events happening at the time. I'll probably annotate those events in the charts. That's the idea for now, at least.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting what your saying but it all depends on the interest of the person asking.. 
If you need to analyse only one day then it's fine. But if I were you I would definitely make an average and make a scatter plot of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze the trends over time for a time period greater than a week, then you can average the count per day and analyze. This would help you look at the trends and (possible)seasonality of the tags.

So, as per your problem statement, I would suggest you go with a scatter plot of the tag counts.

You would also like to have a look at [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165166/number-of-days-in-a-monthly-forecast/165169#165169) which talks about keeping an eye on the varying number of days and weekends in monthly cycles.