# How to De-seasonalize a time series based on trading days?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality, trend

I have a time series of monthly data points with a corresponding cost. Within these months, if you strip out the trend, I believe the cost to be highly correlated to the number of trading (or business days).

What I don't understand is how exactly to strip this out? If the month's trading days can vary (example - January has 21 days one year and 22 another), I don't think I can rely on a typical method of averaging the historical monthly seasonalities.

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/165169/240024 Essentially it suggests dividing the values by the number of trading days in the given month.

Comment: @RyanVolpi very helpful thank you

Comment: Dividing by the number of trading days makes strong assumptions about the impact of a lost day which may not be appropriate depending on the domain. If you look at work productivity for example, losing a day could have an impact equivalent to less than 1 day (if you can plan for it in advance and can prioritize tasks efficiently), or more than 1 day if any day off involves a significant ramp-up period on the way back. More generally you can *measure* the impact of trading days and adjust accordingly. See the X13 documentation (which is standard software for seasonal adjustment), for example.

Comment: @ChrisHaug thank you for the feedback. I had looked into the X13 documentation. The hard part, I found, was being able to explain what is going on inside of that model. It will require more research would could be a "phase 2" forecast analysis.

For these purposes it is systematic (so no planning). The system either runs up expenses or does not run up expenses. That is a great point to make though.